# How do I use Handlebars.js with Karma Runner?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, karma-runner

I am currently adding a .tmpl in Karma using the configuration file like this:

```
        {pattern: 'tmpl/generic/NotificationView.tmpl', included: false},
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to load or being appended in the body. I really don't know how to make that work. I saw there were some handlebars.js preprocessors, but I'm not really sure what that does.

Answer (score 1):

[karma-handlebars-preprocessor](https://github.com/petrbela/karma-handlebars-preprocessor) explains how to add handlebars as preprocessor:

First, I *believe* you must add handlebars to my list of files (I had to).  There is some "code smell" here, for me, because I loaded it from [`node_modules`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs/issues/29), but you could load it from anywhere on your local FileSystem:

```
files: [
    "path/to/handlebars.js"
]
```

Then add handlebars to your list of preprocessors:

```
preprocessors: {
    '**/*.hbs': 'handlebars'
}
```

Next add the preprocessor to plugins:

```
plugins: [
    "karma-handlebars-preprocessor"
]
```

Finally, you need to add some configuration options in it's own block:

```
handlebarsPreprocessor:{
    templates: "Handlebars.templates"
    // configuration continues...
}
```

See the [configuration section](https://github.com/petrbela/karma-handlebars-preprocessor#configuration) for more details.

Also there is a good article that led me to this conclusion: 
https://medium.com/@ryanmurakami/jasmine-unit-testing-with-handlebars-8f6604d0903